# Syntax difference between using Mock and Fake

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am a bit confused in the usage of the keywords **fake** and **mock** depending on the various Mock/TDD frameworks.

I do understand the meaning of a *mock* and of a *fake* and per my understanding I am using this syntax right now:

```
// I prepare my fakes with custom expected behaviours
IUnitOfWork fakeUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
IRepository fakeRepository = new Mock<IRepository>();

// I initialize the mock under test
MyCommandHandler mockHandler = 
   new MyCommandHandler(fakeUnitOfWork.Object, fakeRepository.Object);

// I act on my Mock
mockHandler.Handle(new Command("whatever"));

// I assert
fakeUnitOfWork.Verify(x => x.Commit(), Times.Once());
fakeRepository.Verifx(x => x.Add("whatever"), Times.Once());
```

Is this the correct usage of the prefix *mock* and *fake* or should I use *mock* for `IUnitOfWork` and for `IRepository` and `MyCommandHandler` is just a normal object under test?

Comment: Your mocks are not fakes but mocks, your command handler is not a fake nor a mock but simply the unit under test. See duplicate.